# Python file reading issue

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have .csv file that has different type of data in each field.

File structure is of

```
zbcdexc, 0011222, Ryan, Luke
```

When I do csv read I get error saying "SyntaxError: invalid token". I know in python number starting with 0 are in diffrent base system. How do i read file so that this field can be considered "00111222" as string instead of number ?

Please help.

Current code is

```
with open(epi_csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
myReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in myReader:
    print(row)
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post the exact error message and traceback. I doubt you're seeing this error with that code. And please make sure your indentation is correct. Also, is there really whitespace after each delimiter? That shouldn't be there (but can be ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code, but they don't produce that error message (for example, your code would produce an `IndentationError` before it even started. Another error is that you're opening the file in the wrong way. In Python 3, you mustn't use `rb` mode, instead you have to set the `newline=""` parameter. Also (with your data) you need to skip initial whitespace:

```
with open(epi_csv_file, newline="") as csvfile:
    myReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in myReader:
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
['zbcdexc', '0011222', 'Ryan', 'Luke']
```